# Cannot open image in window

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm doing with tutorial on youtube in this [Python Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKHEtdqhLK8&t=23010s) at 6:23:00 for him is working I don't know what to do.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

#label = an area widget that holds text and/or an image within a window

window = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Kuba\\Desktop\\folder\\images\\3x')

label = Label(window, text='something', font=('Arial',30,'bold'), fg='#00FF00',
              bg='black', bd=10, relied=RAISED, padx=20,pady=20, image=photo)

label.pack()
#label.place(x = 0,y= 0)

window.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\Users\\Kuba\\Desktop\\folder\\programowanie\\nauka programowania python\\nauka po angielsku\\nauka66.py", line 8, in \<module\>
photo = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Kuba\\Desktop\\folder\\images\\3x')
File "C:\\Users\\Kuba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\tkinter\__init_\_.py", line 4093, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, \*\*kw)
File "C:\\Users\\Kuba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\tkinter\__init_\_.py", line 4038, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
\_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\\Users\\Kuba\\Desktop\\folder\\images\\3x": no such file or directory
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? The file or directory doesn't exist, so either it's missing or you typed the path to it or its filename wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies `"C:\Users\Kuba\Desktop\folder\images\3x": no such file or directory`, you either do not have the image or made a typo in the directory. you can change it manually using file explorer to make sure your photo exists in the directory you entered.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path with lower captial "r'.

- photo =
  PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Kuba\Desktop\folder\images\3x\image.png')

Or If the `image.png` is current in the folder, then we use this relative path.

- `photo = PhotoImage(file= "image.png")`

Secondly, You having another `error self.tk.call( _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-relied"`

So remove `relied=RAISED` in Label widget.

Change this:

```
label = Label(window, text='something', font=('Arial',30,'bold'), fg='#00FF00',
              bg='black', bd=10, relied=RAISED, padx=20,pady=20, image=photo)
```

to:

```
label = Label(window, text='something', font=('Arial',30,'bold'), fg='#00FF00',
              bg='black', bd=10, padx=20,pady=20, image=photo)
```

Screenshot:

[image]